# Two buttons on the same column

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Here is an image:

[image]

I'm trying to put a ImageButton in the red box.

I tried layout_toRightof, but it puts the button right next to the rewind button.
I could specify the margin by certain length, but I want it to be relative.

Thank you for the help!!

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/rw"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/rewind">

    </ImageButton>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <ImageView 
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

  <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/rw"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/rewind">
  </ImageButton>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

it is possible

```
<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ImageView 
  android:src="@drawable/icon"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to add the following line to the xml code of the ImageButton

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

I Hope, that's what you wanted, isn't it?

Comment: if I add that, forward image stretches to the right.
[-][-------------] like this

Comment: I thought you had removed it earlier, as it's not in the code provided in the question :p